# spring boot: only for web application development?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to get myself more familiar with Spring Data & Spring Boot. I have looked at examples and couldn't find one that is not used by running it on a server like tomcat etc.

Is it possible to develop a simple client application that just talks to the db and runs on an OS by using spring data or spring boot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run Spring without an application server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116187/is-it-possible-to-run-spring-without-an-application-server)

Comment: those examples to my eyes are a bit old. spring has changed a lot since then. and then there is also spring boot.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Also why would it only be for web development? Just create a spring boot application with the web dependency and be done...

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you by this: 'Just create a spring boot application with the web dependency and be done' ?

Comment: Just as it states. Create a spring boot application without the `spring-boot-web-starter` dependency. The fact that you don't find a sample doesn't mean it isn't possible, just try it before asking questions.

Comment: this looks to be very suitable for my needs if I understand correctly: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @sumitbadaya: the url you provided as a possible duplicate is definitely NOT a duplicate. the other thread talks about Spring, and here "Spring Boot".

Comment: @Alex I want to create a desktop spring boot application and run it without a server... if that makes it clearer.

Comment: Why is this question off topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I undertand, from you're post, The following question:

> How to run spring boot without a web container?

Simply start your spring boot app in a non-web environment:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder() 
    .sources(SpringBootApp.class) 
    .web(false) 
    .run(args);
```

Also, you obviously should not add the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.

By default, spring boot launches a web container if it finds one in the classpath. Using `web(false)` ensures that it does not happen. Tomcat could be included by another dependency without your knowledge, so it's better to disable the web environment if that is your goal.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ this example doesn't have the mentioned dependency and seems suitable, if I am correct.

Comment: web(false) simply insures that if tomcat is found in the classpath, spring boot will not use it. The example you provided does not have web dependencies, so it also works. Just cleaner/bullet proof  with web(false) in my opinion